# Vim autoindent does not work in 8.0.1097

Tags: vim

I have an identical vim setup on vim 8.0.1097 and vim 7.4 but the autoindent behaviour differs:

In vim 8:

```
if [ "$u" != "root" ]
    then
        a
        b
        c
        fi
```

And in Vim 7 it works fine.

Vim 8 `:set` shows:

```
--- Options ---
  autoindent          commentstring=#%s   hidden              incsearch           matchtime=2         scrolloff=7         smartcase           tabstop=4           ttymouse=xterm      t_vb=
  background=dark     expandtab           history=700         laststatus=2        modified            shiftwidth=4        smarttab            textwidth=79        viminfo=%,'20,"50
  cindent             filetype=sh         hlsearch            lazyredraw          ruler               showmatch         noswapfile            timeoutlen=500      wildmenu
  cmdheight=2         helplang=en         ignorecase          linebreak           scroll=31           showtabline=2       syntax=sh           ttyfast           nowritebackup
  backspace=eol,start,indent
  completeopt=menuone,longest,preview
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
  fileformats=unix,dos,mac
  grepprg=grep -nH $*
  guicursor=n-v-c:block,o:hor50,i-ci:hor15,r-cr:hor30,sm:block,a:blinkon0
  indentexpr=GetShIndent()
  indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,e,0=then,0=do,0=else,0=elif,0=fi,0=esac,0=done,0=end,),0=;;,0=;&,0=fin,0=fil,0=fip,0=fir,0=fix
  runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp,~/.vim/bundle/indentLine,~/.vim/bundle/javacomplete,~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim,~/.vim/bundle/nerdcommenter,~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree,~/.vim/bundle/supertab,~/.vim/bundle/syntastic,~/.vim/bundle/vim-fugit
ive,~/.vim/bundle/vim-repeat,~/.vim/bundle/vim-surround,~/.vim/bundle/vim-tmux-navigator,~/.vim/bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/after,~/.vim
/bundle/indentLine/after,~/.vim/after
  statusline= %{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h %w  CWD: %r%{getcwd()}%h   Line: %l Column: %c
  switchbuf=useopen,usetab,newtab
  whichwrap=b,s,<,>,h,l
  wildignore=*.o,*~,*.pyc
```

And vim 7.4 `:set` shows:

```
--- Options ---
  autoindent          commentstring=#%s   filetype=sh         hlsearch            lazyredraw          scroll=31           showtabline=2       syntax=sh           ttyfast           nowritebackup
  background=dark     cscopetag           helplang=en         ignorecase          linebreak           scrolloff=7         smartcase           tabstop=4           ttymouse=xterm      t_vb=
  cindent             cscopeverbose       hidden              incsearch           matchtime=2         shiftwidth=4        smarttab            textwidth=79        viminfo=%,'20,"50
  cmdheight=2         expandtab           history=700         laststatus=2        ruler               showmatch         noswapfile            timeoutlen=500      wildmenu
  backspace=eol,start,indent
  completeopt=menuone,longest,preview
  cscopeprg=/usr/bin/cscope
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
  fileformats=unix,dos,mac
  grepprg=grep -nH $*
  guicursor=n-v-c:block,o:hor50,i-ci:hor15,r-cr:hor30,sm:block,a:blinkon0
  indentexpr=GetShIndent()
  indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,e,0=then,0=do,0=else,0=elif,0=fi,0=esac,0=done,),0=;;,0=;&,0=fin,0=fil,0=fip,0=fir,0=fix
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.
  runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp,~/.vim/bundle/indentLine,~/.vim/bundle/javacomplete,~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim,~/.vim/bundle/nerdcommenter,~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree,~/.vim/bundle/supertab,~/.vim/bundle/syntastic,~/.vim/bundle/vim-fugit
ive,~/.vim/bundle/vim-repeat,~/.vim/bundle/vim-surround,~/.vim/bundle/vim-tmux-navigator,~/.vim/bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/after,~/.vim
/bundle/indentLine/after,~/.vim/after
  statusline= %{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h %w  CWD: %r%{getcwd()}%h   Line: %l Column: %c
  switchbuf=useopen,usetab,newtab
  whichwrap=b,s,<,>,h,l
  wildignore=*.o,*~,*.pyc
```

The difference are:

```
     --- Options ---
-      autoindent          commentstring=#%s   hidden              incsearch           matchtime=2         scrolloff=7         smartcase           tabstop=4           ttymouse=xterm      t_vb=
-      background=dark     expandtab           history=700         laststatus=2        modified            shiftwidth=4        smarttab            textwidth=79        viminfo=%,'20,"50
-      cindent             filetype=sh         hlsearch            lazyredraw          ruler               showmatch         noswapfile            timeoutlen=500      wildmenu
-      cmdheight=2         helplang=en         ignorecase          linebreak           scroll=31           showtabline=2       syntax=sh           ttyfast           nowritebackup
+      autoindent          commentstring=#%s   filetype=sh         hlsearch            lazyredraw          scroll=31           showtabline=2       syntax=sh           ttyfast           nowritebackup
+      background=dark     cscopetag           helplang=en         ignorecase          linebreak           scrolloff=7         smartcase           tabstop=4           ttymouse=xterm      t_vb=
+      cindent             cscopeverbose       hidden              incsearch           matchtime=2         shiftwidth=4        smarttab            textwidth=79        viminfo=%,'20,"50
+      cmdheight=2         expandtab           history=700         laststatus=2        ruler               showmatch         noswapfile            timeoutlen=500      wildmenu
       backspace=eol,start,indent
       completeopt=menuone,longest,preview
+      cscopeprg=/usr/bin/cscope
       fileencoding=utf-8
       fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
       fileformats=unix,dos,mac
       grepprg=grep -nH $*
       guicursor=n-v-c:block,o:hor50,i-ci:hor15,r-cr:hor30,sm:block,a:blinkon0
       indentexpr=GetShIndent()
-      indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,e,0=then,0=do,0=else,0=elif,0=fi,0=esac,0=done,0=end,),0=;;,0=;&,0=fin,0=fil,0=fip,0=fir,0=fix
+      indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,e,0=then,0=do,0=else,0=elif,0=fi,0=esac,0=done,),0=;;,0=;&,0=fin,0=fil,0=fip,0=fir,0=fix
+      iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.
       runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp,~/.vim/bundle/indentLine,~/.vim/bundle/javacomplete,~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim,~/.vim/bundle/nerdcommenter,~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree,~/.vim/bundle/supertab,~/.vim/bundle/syntastic,~/.vim/bundle/vim-fugit
-    ive,~/.vim/bundle/vim-repeat,~/.vim/bundle/vim-surround,~/.vim/bundle/vim-tmux-navigator,~/.vim/bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/after,~/.vim
+    ive,~/.vim/bundle/vim-repeat,~/.vim/bundle/vim-surround,~/.vim/bundle/vim-tmux-navigator,~/.vim/bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/after,~/.vim
     /bundle/indentLine/after,~/.vim/after
       statusline= %{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h %w  CWD: %r%{getcwd()}%h   Line: %l Column: %c
       switchbuf=useopen,usetab,newtab
```

Top 4 differences are actually just in different order, the number of items is the same. I tried to manually set `cscopeprg` to match the value of what vim 7.4 has, it makes no difference.

I do not understand which part my vim config could cause such behaviour.

List of my plugins (all latest):
`ctrlp  indentLine  javacomplete  jedi-vim  nerdcommenter  nerdtree  supertab  syntastic  vim-fugitive  vim-repeat  vim-surround  vim-tmux-navigator  vim-trailing-whitespace`

I also tried to remove all of my plugins and vim 8 is still malfunctioning.

Using downgrade method, I re-installed vim to 8.0.662 and 8.0.1030, the indentation during typing works perfectly. I think there is a bug to the newer version of vim.

Comment: Do you mean when typing, or when selecting all and pressing `=` ? Or both?

Comment: `=` works, this only happen during typing.

Comment: what does `:filetype` gives in both vim version?

Comment: Looks like a regression

Comment: The procedure to follow in those cases, with links inside this time: 
If you thing you have discovered a bug or a regression, then you should either contact the developers on [vim_dev mailing list](https://vim.sourceforge.io/maillist.php), or open an issue on [vim github page](https://github.com/vim/vim). 

In case you have a doubt whether it's a problem on vim side or on yours, start with a mail on vim_dev. SO is really an improper channel to address this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is indeed due to a [bug](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2151) in Vim which was introduced in version [8.0.1041](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1041), and has since been fixed in version [8.0.1154](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1154).  You should be able to fix this by upgrading to the newest version from upstream.